# How to determine if a username is correct?

Tags: java, usernametoken

I need to determine if a username in the form of an email (something@something.com) is in the correct form. The necessary parameters for the username being correct are as follows:

1. there is something before the @ symbol
2. there is text between the @ symbol and the ".com"
3. the username ends in .com

These are the only parameters, if they are met the method will return true and if they are all not met it will return false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static boolean isCorrectUsername(String username){
    var atPosition = username.indexOf("@");
    return atPosition > 0 && username.endsWith(".com") &&  username.length() > atPosition + 5;
}
```

Comment: Answering questions with no context whatsoever isn't a good way to answer questions. Especially questions that smell of homework.

Comment: technically it is extra credit on a 30 point assingment